# Rails force reload of javascript after render

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, render

I'm using a form in my rails application, in my controller at the end I check if the content of the form is ok or not, if not I render the page again explaining on top the errors

part of controller

```
 if @insertion.save
          redirect_to @insertion
        else
          render 'new'
        end
```

and in my view I've got this line to show the errors.

```
<% if @insertion.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        The form contains <%= pluralize(@insertion.errors.count, "error") %>.
      </div>
      <ul>
        <% @insertion.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

the problem is that after the render the page will not load again my javascript file, so the view isn't as I expected

How can I force to reload js after render?

this is my coffee file due to turbolink

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  insertionJS = new Insertion()
  if $('.insertions.show').length > 0
    console.log("insertions.show")
    insertionJS.showJS() .....continue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Turbolinks by design JavaScript and CSS are not reloaded, it turns your links etc. into XHR requests then uses the response to update `<body>` and trigger its special events (also why the jQuery `$(function() { ... });` does not work as intended with Turbolinks. Since its doing an XHR, its not a real page load at all, even if it looks like one to the Rails controller.

For most cases you can use `turbolinks:load` event like you showed, but that is not a magix solution, and you must still remember that all your "old" JavaScript and HTML still exists, that any JavaScript "globals" wont be reset, etc.

If you want to be reloading/executing JavaScript on every page, just remove Turbolinks from your application (`Gemfile`, `application.js`). If you implement proper cache headers for your CSS/JS and dont have too much JS, the performance difference is not that big.

If you just want to disable it for a specific page/link/form for some reason, you can add the [`data-turbolinks="false"` attribute](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#disabling-turbolinks-on-specific-links) to the link. Remember this needs to be on the link leading to the page, not the page itself. For the page itself to really reload, you could do like `location.reload()`, but remember thats a complete seperate page reload after your render/redirect.

If you really want to force JavaScript to reload, you could insert another `<script>` into head dynamically, but remember that your original JavaScript *is still loaded*, so thats likely to be a pain.

Id note that Turbolinks is actually pretty large and complex, so it would be worth reading its own documentation rather than just the small snippets from Rails.   https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

Comment: I 'solved' this issue creating a function that generate a string with inside the html used to show the errors and then I passed it to flash[:danger]. In my view I use flash.html_safe to render the message as html. Thanks anyway