# Disable merging of a specific head script in Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

I'm working on a Rails app that renders a JavaScript in the `head` of `application.html.erb` with the following:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script><%= render 'certified_mail/mail_list_loader.js' %></script>
</head>
```

The JS partial rendered with the code above makes an AJAX call with parameters passed via instance variables from the controller:

```
# _mail_list_loader.js.erb
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/certified_mail/mail_list',
    type: 'get',
    data: {
      page: <%= @page %>,
      rut: <%= @rut || 'null' %>,
      from: <%= @from || 'null' %>,
      to: <%= @to || 'null' %>,
      ids: <%= @outdated_message_ids.to_json.html_safe %>
    }
  });
});
```

Since Turbolinks merges the `head` content from subsequent requests, every time the parameters for the AJAX calls change I have an extra `script` being loaded in the `head`, which results in unwanted extra requests, as shown in the image below:

[image: Extra scripts being added to head]

How can I tell Turbolinks to not consider that specific script in the merging process so I can avoid having those extra calls?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I tell Turbolinks to not consider that specific script in the merging process so I can avoid having those extra calls?

I'm afraid I don't think there is a nice way to do what you're asking. If the instance variables have changed, then the script will need to be appended and evaluated.

I'd recommend a different approach, like [the solution I proposed in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46554016/783009).

I think what you're after is to teardown the event listener, and remove the script once it has executed. I wouldn't recommend this, as it is unconventional, and a bit flaky, but it is possible.

```
<script id="mail-list-loader">
  // Remove the previously added event listener
  document.removeEventListener('turbolinks:load', mailListLoader)

  // Redefine the event handler and bind to the load event
  var mailListLoader = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/certified_mail/mail_list',
      type: 'get',
      data: {
        page: <%= @page %>,
        rut: <%= @rut || 'null' %>,
        from: <%= @from || 'null' %>,
        to: <%= @to || 'null' %>,
        ids: <%= @outdated_message_ids.to_json.html_safe %>
      }
    })
  }
  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', mailListLoader)

  // Remove the script to prevent build up in the head
  document.head.removeChild(document.getElementById('mail-list-loader'))
</script>
```

As I said, I wouldn't recommend this, as you may end up with more headaches down the line, but it serves as a demonstration of what effectively needs to happen.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about placing the script tag inside the `<body>` tag? In my case, I want some stylesheet `<link>` tags to be only applied to one page but not merged with another page `<link>` tags when the page changes. So I ended up moving those tags that don't need to be merged inside the `<body>`.